# SFDX ERROR: Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined

Tags: salesforcedx

I am getting an error when trying to do a sfdx retrieve:

ERROR:  Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined.

Here is the command that is being issued in VS Code when I click on the package.xml file and retrive source from org:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest c:\hilton\BossReno\manifest\package.xml
```

The development environment is Salesforce Spring 2019
Here is my version of sfdx:

sfdx-cli/6.53.0-67a9cbb60c (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4

Here is my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Is `c:_hilton\ ` a typo? Should be `\ ` instead of `_`.

Comment: It took out the backslash when I posted the stackoverflow question.  it is c:\\_hilton

Comment: Just like in programming, you have to escape your backslashes. I'll fix it for you. (Or use a code block like I did).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with the CLI on Windows, you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/33).

I tried today after running `sfdx update` (I'm now running salesforcedx 45.3.4 (core)), and it's fixed.

Try updating the CLI and run the command again.

If it's not working, please post your CLI version (running `sfdx plugins --core`), and add a comment on the [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/33).

A workaround is to use `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` with the following package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <types>
            <members>*</members>
            <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
        </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Posted new issue.  This is for the AuraDefinitionBundle not the LightningComponentBundle.  https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/39